# Heroku : sh: 1: nuxt: not found Error when Pushing

Tags: node.js, git, rest, express, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my local RESTful Node.js app on heroku. I followed the instructions given in the Heroku website (under the deploy section of the application), and when I run the command

`git push heroku master`

I get a really weird build error stating :

```
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:        
remote:        > resthub@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_9839e223
remote:        > npm run build
remote:
remote:        
remote:        > resthub@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_9839e223
remote:        > nuxt build
remote:
remote: sh: 1: nuxt: not found
```

I googled and I realised theres a framework nuxt.js? But I did not use Nuxt.js in this application at all. I'm not sure why is the build trying to run nuxt build? Hence I really cannot figure out what's the error.

Here's my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "resthub",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.x",
    "npm": "6.x"
  },
  "description": "An app demonstrating RESTful API implementation",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "api",
    "restful",
    "json"
  ],
  "author": "Chen Kaibin",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.7"
  },
}
```

Comment: The output says 'Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts', but I see  neither in your `package.json`. Is that file at the very top directory of your project? Are you trying to deploy a server-side application _and_ a client at the same time? Do you have multiple `package.json` files?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. That was what I found to be very strange too. The package.json is at the root folder of the project, and that is the only package.json file. And I'm only running a client side application.

Comment: Did you use some kind of starter code? Do you have multiple branches? Are you _entirely sure_ that the `package.json` you're showing here is the one you're including in your push to Heroku? If you `grep` (or similar) through your source code, do you find any mention of `nuxt`?

Comment: Ok I fixed the issue, I just re-setup my entire application, and it somehow works.

Comment: Really have no idea what went wrong, I just re-setup the whole app, copied my source code files over, did all the npm install and everything, and then tried again and it just somehow works. Thanks for the help though